# Pass color of text from label to variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table with a few lines and on each line I have a text box that, when I change the text it changes the color of the text.
I want to pass to a variable the color of that text.

How can I pass the color of the text to a variable?

```
var cor = document.getElementById('conteudo_pagina_quantidade' + i).style.color;
```

Comment: That depends on how the color is assigned to the text, and what is the actual target. Currently we have `label` and `textbox` as candidates.

Comment: You have ansewerd in your question

Comment: @Keyur Not necessarily, if the color is changed by CSS, then the inline style doesn't know the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add an event listener to all text boxes, and take their value, then change the color to that value:

```js
for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
  var cor = document.getElementById('conteudo_pagina_quantidade' + i);
  cor.addEventListener('keyup', function(){ // to make it live, changes on every key stroke
    var val = this.value; // take the value
    this.style.color = val; // change the color with value
  });
}
```

```html
<input id="conteudo_pagina_quantidade1" placeholder="Color...">
<input id="conteudo_pagina_quantidade2" placeholder="Color...">
<input id="conteudo_pagina_quantidade3" placeholder="Color...">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) for recover the computed style of an element.

```
const el = document.getElementById('conteudo_pagina_quantidade' + i);
const clr = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("color");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see that the line

```
var cor = document.getElementById('conteudo_pagina_quantidade' + i).style.color;
```

works as expected. You get the `color` of the input text box.

```js
for(var i=1; i<=3; i++){
  var cor = document.getElementById('conteudo_pagina_quantidade' +   i).style.color;
  console.log(cor);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='conteudo_pagina_quantidade1' style='color:red;'/>
<input type='text' id='conteudo_pagina_quantidade2' style='color:green;'/>
<input type='text' id='conteudo_pagina_quantidade3' style='color:blue;'/>
```